# Напишите функцию, которая принимает закодированную строку и возвращает объект в соответствии со следующим примером:

Tags: javascript

Задание 2 Напишите функцию, которая принимает закодированную строку и возвращает объект в соответствии со следующим примером:

```
parseCode("John000Doe000123") ➞ {  firstName: "John",  lastName: "Doe",  id: "123"}
parseCode("michael0smith004331") ➞ {  firstName: "michael",  lastName: "smith",  id: "4331"}
parseCode("Thomas00LEE0000043") ➞ {  firstName: "Thomas",  lastName: "LEE",  id: "43"}
```

```js
function parseCode(str) {
    let firstName = "";
    let lastName = "";
    let id = "";
    let zero = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === "0" && zero === 0) {
            firstName = str.slice(0, i);
            str = str.slice(i + 3);
            i = -1;
            zero++;
        } else if (str[i] === "0" && zero === 1) {
            lastName = str.slice(0, i);
            str = str.slice(i + 3);
            i = -1;
            zero++;
        } else if (str[i] === "0" && zero === 2) {
            id = str.slice(0, i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        id: id
    };
}

console.log(parseCode("John000Doe000123"))
console.log(parseCode("michael0smith004331"))
console.log(parseCode("Thomas00LEE0000043"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Сначала я разберу Ваш код, почему он не работал, мне важно было понять как Вы думали, поэтому я и свое решение написал на основе Вашего кода, но значительно переработал его, до не узнаваемости, мое решение будет попозже.

В первом условии вы добавляете `3`  тут `str = str.slice(i + 3);` но это не совсем верно так как количество нулей после имени в каждом случае разное поэтому у вас обрезало фамилиию:

```
John    + 000 = Doe000123" 
michael + 0sm = ith004331"
Thomas  + 00L = EE0000043"
```

В последнем условии у Вас не учитывается что в конце строки не будет нулей, а будет конец строки поэтому я добавил условие `i === str.length -1`, что касается `str` то решение интересное, но не для такого случая, поэтому, я решил использовать другую переменную `end_zero` обозначающую позицию последнего нуля в цепочке нулей +1 —  т.е. получается это будет первой буквой слова, *я взял их в квадратные скобки для наглядности тут*:

```
John 000[D]oe000[1]23
michael0[s]mith00[4]331
Thomas00[L]EE00000[4]3
```

Таким образом слово я обрезаю от `end_zero` до `i`, а в последнем случае  с `id` до конца и перевожу в число через `+`.

И мне нужно добавить 4 условие, чтобы максимально сохранить Вашу логику и заставить код работать.

```js
function parseCode(str) {
    let firstName = "";
    let lastName = "";
    let id = "";
    let zero = 0;
    let end_zero = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === "0" && zero === 0) {
            firstName = str.slice(0, i);
            // str = str.slice(i + 3);
            //i = -1;
            zero++;
        //} else if (str[i] === "0" && zero === 1) {            
        } else if (str[i] === "0" && str[i-1] !="0" && zero === 1) {
            //lastName = str.slice(0, i);
            lastName = str.slice(end_zero, i);
            //str = str.slice(i + 3);
            //i = -1;
            zero++;
        //} else if (str[i] === "0" && zero === 2) {
        } else if (i === str.length - 1 && zero === 2) {  
            //id = str.slice(0, i);
            id = +str.slice(end_zero);
            //break;
        } 
        /* + */
        else if ( str[i] === "0" && str[i + 1] !== "0" && zero > 0){
            end_zero = i + 1
        } 
    }
    return {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        id
    };
}

console.log(parseCode("John000Doe000123"))
console.log(parseCode("michael0smith004331"))
console.log(parseCode("Thomas00LEE0000043"))
```

В синтаксисе JS c ES6 можно писать так (это создаст объект из где ключами будут имена переменных, а значениями их же значения — удобно):

```
{
    firstName,
    lastName,
    id
};
```

Теперь я добавлю свои вариант, в  нем сложно допустить ошибку так как он достаточно легко читается единственный сложный момент это понять что тут:

```
result[Object.keys(result)[idx]]
```

Это обращение к свойству по индексу `Object.keys(result)` мне вернет три свойства в строгом порядке так как объект не модифицировался с момента создания. Таким образом я могу обратится к свойству через `idx`

Плюсы этого кода то что решение найдено путем алгоритма, а не просто регулярных выражений (я их часто использую),но я советую как минимум изучить это решение и понять как оно работает, это поможет Вам в будущем писать такой же код или еще лучше и надежнее. Короткие решения хороши, но не всегда понятны я стараюсь соблюдать баланс понятности и краткости, ну и конечно рекомендую овладеть регулярными выражениями.

```js
function parseCode(str) {
    const result = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        id: ''
    };
    let idx = 0
    let is_zero = false
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] != "0"){
            is_zero = false
            result[Object.keys(result)[idx]] += str[i]
        } else if (is_zero === false){
            is_zero = true
            idx++
        } 
    }
    return result
}
console.log(parseCode("John000Doe000123"))
console.log(parseCode("michael0smith004331"))
console.log(parseCode("Thomas00LEE0000043"))
```

И я решил добавить еще решение с регуляркой, вдруг Вам понравится с ними работать)

```js
function parseCode(str) {
    const [firstName, lastName, id] = str.split(/0+/)
    return {firstName, lastName, id}
}

console.log(parseCode("John000Doe000123"))
console.log(parseCode("michael0smith004331"))
console.log(parseCode("Thomas00LEE0000043"))
```

Хотя вопрос не про регулярки, но добавлю еще один вариант который будет искать id с нулями:

```js
function parseCode(str) {
    const [firstName, lastName, id] = str.match(/^([A-z]+)|([A-z]+)|([1-9][0-9]+)$/g)
    return {firstName, lastName, id}
}

console.log(parseCode("John000Doe000100203"))
console.log(parseCode("michael0smith0043031"))
console.log(parseCode("Thomas00LEE00000403"))
```

Comment: @Dannil Loban феноминально, большое спасибо за развернутый ответ!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста, мне было Важно чтобы Вы смогли разобраться, теперь Вы можете написать код по-своему зная причину.

Comment: Последнее решение ломается на `id` с нулями (`John0Doe0100500`)

Comment: Моё решение: `function parseCode(str) { return { .../^(?<firstName>[a-z]+)0+(?<lastName>[a-z]+)0+(?<id>\d+)$/i.exec(str).groups }; }` =)

Comment: Это конкретное решение будет ломаться, так как расчет идет на то что нули это только разделители, но его можно доработать, правда регулярка не будет такой лаконичной, просто не хочу человека отпугивать от них)

Comment: @AlexeyTen вполне себе вариант, мне нравится

Comment: Ну да, тут автор не сказал бывают ли в id нули, но я бы на всякий случай предположил что бывают =)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145361/discussion-between-daniil-loban-and-alexey-ten).

Answer (score 1):

Вроде работает :)

```js
function parseCode(str) {
    const [firstName, lastName, id] = str.split(/0\s*/).filter(e => e !== "")
    return {firstName, lastName, id}
}

console.log(parseCode("John000Doe000123"))
console.log(parseCode("michael0smith004331"))
console.log(parseCode("Thomas00LEE0000043"))
console.log(parseCode("John0Doe0100500"))
```

ps.. решение не работает если пользователь ввел `0` либо в `ID` есть `0`

Comment: а мой код как-то можно исправить?

Comment: Если ваш, то ответ в посте рядом

Comment: Это решение ломается на `id` с нулями (`John0Doe0100500`)